# Settings in windows search are in a wrong language

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, localization

Today I switched my system language from Polish to English (Windows 10). Everything works except Windows Search. When I type `Add or remove` to get to `Add or remove program` I'm getting polish version of this `Dodaj lub usuń program`. When I click it I get this window:

[image: Language settings]

Of course I type `Add or remove` in Windows Search, not in this window's searchbox.

Comment: Order of language matters. Check if _English_ is listed above all other languages in _Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language_ and restart.

Comment: @Michael D Currently I have only english language on my pc. It makes my problem more freaky :/. Also I've tried to rebuild index and nothing.

Comment: Alright, lets try another one. Go to _Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings_ and change _Override for Windows display language_ to the desired language. Restart.

Comment: Still nothing. Maybe it's a bug?

Comment: I am not sure. But I am sorry, I am out of ideas.